# Why variance is $\frac{\lambda}{t}$ here?

Tags: r, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution

I was going through an assignment from Coursera where i found out this [image: this]

Why here **variance** is $\frac{\lambda}{t}$ ? As for Poisson's distribution both variance and lambda are same i.e. **$\lambda$=variance**. Then how is it possible ?

Comment: If $X \sim \mathcal P(\lambda t)$ then $$\text{Var}\left(\frac{X}{t} \right )  = \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{t^2} = \frac{\lambda t}{t^2} = \frac{\lambda}{t}$$

Comment: @winperikle Can you explain in bit detail , i didn't understand properly..

Comment: If you have a random variable $X$ and a constant $c$ then $\text{Var}(cX) = c^2 \text{Var}(X)$, this is a general property of the variance. Here we have $X$ that follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$ thus $\text{Var}(X) = \lambda t$ and $c= \frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: @winperikle  I got it , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about variance, we should be careful to clarify the **variance of what** is concerned. If the concern is the **variance of the number of occurrences** in a unit time interval, then the **mean and the variance of the occurrence number** are equal, both equal to $X/t$ with your notations.

On the other hand, if the concern is the **variance of the estimated $\lambda$**, then it (approximately) equals the estimated $\lambda/t$.

Comment: Thanks but i asked about **variance** not **lambda**

Comment: **λ_1=λ_t / t -----------  

λ_t = 5 , t= 94.32**

Hence **λ_1=5/94.32** which is equal to **V_1** , right ? So **V_1==5/94.32** but in problem above it  is **5/(94.32)^2**.
It cannot be solved this way.


Thanks for the effort but your explanation is wrong and i feel @winperikle explained it why this is so.

Comment: @Abhishek soni: OK, now  I understand your concern. I have updated my above answer, which hopefully answers your question.